# Error adding 'import lettuce' on PyCharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm, lettuce

I have a problem with Python and `lettuce`.

I already install the `pip` and `lettuce` in Python 2.7, and I'm trying to create a `.features` file and a `.py` file for the steps. The problem is that when I put the line `from lettuce import *` I have an error that says:

*"Unresolved reference lettuce..."* and then: *"this inspection detects names that should resolved but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items"*.

I really don´t know how to fix this problem. Can anyone can help me please?

Comment: It's only PyCharm being daft, your code should still run.

Comment: What you mean? When I try to run the file I have an error saying `ImportError: No module named lettuce`. It doesn´t look like PyCharm in daft. Or maybe yes, but I still don´t know how to fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the problem. What I did, just in case anyone has the same problem is:

In my PyCharm project:

- press Ctrl+Alt+s to open the settings
- on the left column, select Project Interpreter
- on the top right there is a list of python binaries found on your system, pick the right one
- eventually click the + button to install additional python modules
- validate

[image]

Just in case you are not able to add an other module (that happened to me as well) you can change the project interpreter.

Hope this works!